# UIScrollView losing touch events

Tags: iphone, objective-c, uiscrollview, touch

i have a scroll view in my application and i want that when the user scrolls it down, so its contentOffset.y reaches -50, the scroll view will animate to the bottom of the screen (at this point the scrollview won't be visible).

I managed to do this, but when i animate my scrollview back so it gets visible again it loses touch events and won't scroll anymore.

i already tried to set scrollEnabled and userInteractionEnabled to YES but nothing works. If someone could help i would appreciate.

Thanks.

**This is the code when i animate my scroll view to the bottom of the screen**

```
[UIView animateWithDuration:0.5 animations:^
     {     
         CGRect scrollRect = self.scrollView.frame;
         CGRect newFrame = CGRectMake(scrollRect.origin.x, 367, scrollRect.size.width, self.scrollView.contentSize.height);
         self.scrollView.frame = newFrame;
     }
     completion:^(BOOL finished)
     {
         self.navigationItem.leftBarButtonItem = [[[UIBarButtonItem alloc] initWithBarButtonSystemItem:UIBarButtonSystemItemDone target:self action:@selector(doneButtonPressed:)] autorelease];
     }];
```

**And this is the code where i make my scroll view visible again**

```
[UIView animateWithDuration:0.5 animations:^
 {
     CGRect scrollRect = self.scrollView.frame;
     CGRect newFrame = CGRectMake(scrollRect.origin.x, 0, scrollRect.size.width, self.scrollView.contentSize.height);
     self.scrollView.frame = newFrame;
 }
 completion:^(BOOL finished)
 {
     self.navigationItem.leftBarButtonItem = nil;
     self.scrollView.scrollEnabled = YES;
     self.scrollView.userInteractionEnabled = YES;
     _canScroll = YES;
 }];
```

and after that i can't scroll it anymore.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are setting scroll view height as self.scrollView.contentSize.height so scroll view will not be scrollable vertically.Try by changing it to self.scrollview.frame.height

Comment: Thanks very much! i changed to self.scrollview.frame.size.height and it worked. Sorry for disturbing you guys!